# Fetching data from external XML with Alloy in Titanium

Tags: backbone.js, collections, xmlhttprequest, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on my very first iPhone application made in Appcelerator Titanium. I'm using the Alloy framework.

I only have a general JavaScript background. I Have read up on how BackboneJS works, however I am struggling with the concept.

The app is very basic, all I need is to fetch an URL which contains a XML response. Example: http://www.domain.com/api.php?listProducts

This URL will respons something like this

```
<response>
<request>
<timestamp id="0.66266400 1357656226"/>
<status id="100">OK</status>
</request>
<api_function>getproductsimage</api_function>
<products>
<product id="1">
<images>
<image name="featured" width="640" height="347" src="../html/productImages/featured.jpg"/>
<image name="nonretina" width="125" height="95" src="../html/productImages/thumbnail.jpg"/>
<image name="retina" width="250" height="190" src="../html/productImages/thumbnail.jpg"/>
<image name="ldpi" width="" height="" src=""/>
<image name="mdpi" width="" height="" src=""/>
<image name="hdpi" width="" height="" src=""/>
<image name="xhdpi" width="" height="" src=""/>
</images>
</product>
</product>
</products>
</response>
```

I want to handle this data in a TableView and obviously there will be more than one response. However I don't really understand the documentation about making an XHR in BackboneJS. Would anyone be able to help me make a simple collection / model for simply fetching this URL and displaying the data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is is purely a [backbonejs Model parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) issue since backbone works with JSON responses and you are looking at return XML.

There is no requirement that you use Alloy models to solve this problem so you can just implement your solution with http requests and populate the objects yourself.

Comment: Here's the link for "mrbrandbart" to the Ti.Network.HTTPClient you'll probably want to use: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback. We went and changed our API from feeding XML results to JSON instead. Just finished with some hardcoded demo JSON examples and going to try make a model and a collection with that now.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: no problem, Alloy is good framework, but understanding the basics of BackboneJS Models and Collections will go a long way towards making your life easier. Here are some links of work that I have done that might help you out http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/34758523772/appcelerator-alloy-links